# Number of 7 digit numbers which satisfy the given conditions

Tags: combinatorics

Let the number string be $abcdefg$, where $a,b,c,\dots, g$ are digits from $\{1,\ldots,9\}$ then find the number of 7 digit numbers which satisfy
$$
a < b < c< d> e> f> g
$$
Repetition of digits is allowed
I tried to make up cases of different values of $d $ but by taking every different value there seem to be many cases I can't think of any other method other than making cases which make it quite difficult for me. I would like a hint.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Can't think where to start with. I got many problems where this kinda condition arise but I am stuck please help!!

Comment: What did I do to get -2 votes ?

Comment: To avoid this question, I would add comments to down votes.

Comment: I miss one piece of information: Can each digit appear more than once in the number string or not?

Comment: Yes there can be repetition of digitts

Comment: Edit your question to add your 2 comments explaining your difficulty, and the clarificarion re repetititon of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of what others have said, this is best expressed as a sum, since finding the actual number is rather tedious. We'll have to assume that this is what your instructor wants, unless you're also expected to do tedious calculations or be able to code out the answer (though that isn't too complicated).

We know that $d$ must have at least $3$ nonzero digits less than it, so it must be at least $4$, and can be at most $9$, since there are no limits on how large it can be. Once we know what $d$ is, we limit $a,b,c$ and $e,f,g$ to the subset $S=\{1,2,3...d-1\}$, where they obey the given inequalities.

Because of those inequalities, it turns out that counting the number of ways of picking $a,b,c$ and $e,f,g$ is not so bad; since they follow a strict inequality, it is the same as counting the size $3$ subsets of $S$. This is because once we pick which $3$ distinct elements from that set will be digits, we also know which will be $a,b,$ and $c$ based on which is greatest.

For example, if $d=6$, and I use $1,4,5$ for my $a,b,$ and $c$, I know that I must have $a=1, b=4, c=5$ to obey the given rules. This is also true for $e,f,$ and $g$. Also note that since choosing $a,b,$ and $c$ is independent of choosing $e,f,$ and $g$ (in the sense that choices for one group does not affect choices for the other group, though they both depend on choice of $d$), I count them separately and multiply out the number of ways of picking each.

This gives $\sum _{d=4}^9 \binom{d-1}{3}^2$.

The actual number...you can find if you take a few minutes with a calculator.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, understood it well

Answer (score 1):

Hint : There is only 3 choices for $g$. Try considering them separately.

Comment: 1234321 , 1568765 , 1239876, 5678123 well according to me there might be more possibilities for g

Comment: My error. I did not see the inequalities changed in the middle.

Comment: $d$ can only be $4..9$. Left and right of $d$ you have ${d-1} \choose 3$. Multiply, summation, too bad it is not a closed formula of a single term. Evaluate if you want a number.

Comment: I didn't get what u r trying to convey please explain in detail